# Rework blackjack game

Tags: java, blackjack

I'm trying to create a blackjack game, where the player starts off with 2 cards, and then asked if he/she would like to have another card (user input: yes or no), if yes, another card is added to the total. if no, the game just terminates.

Here is a sample output I'm trying to get:

[image]

And this is what I have so far (It's probably wrong in terms of the placement):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BlackJackGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int randomnum1 = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 10);
        int randomnum2 = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 10);
        int randomnum3 = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 10);
        int total;
        char anotherCard = 'y';

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("First cards: " + randomnum1 + ", " + randomnum2);

        total = randomnum1 + randomnum2;

        System.out.println("Total: " + total);

        while (anotherCard != 'n')
        {   
            System.out.print("Card: " + randomnum3);

            System.out.print("Do you want another card? (y/n): ");
            anotherCard = input.next().charAt(0);           
        }   
    }
}
```

Tips and reworking the source code will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Also, I'm having a hard time creating the accumulator for the cards. For example, say my first 2 cards are 2 & 9. It then asks me if I want a another card, I say "yes." then next card is 2. So, my total would be 13. How do you keep a running total like that? The goal is not to go over 21. Can an if-else statement involved in this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow! To be effective on this site, we ask you to please ask specific questions, and to provide information about what you've already tried. If you do this, we'll be happy to help you

Comment: It's nice (and rare) to see a new user's question with actual effort put into it. Nice job!

Answer (score 1):

As Far as card games go, there are 52 cards in a deck, and I'm assuming there's one deck.

If you want it to be a fair game, then you have to keep that in mind.

But if you just want output to look correct, you just have to avoid getting more than 4 aces, 2's, 3's, and 4's.

One way to achieve this would be to make an int array of size 52 with 4 of each card.  I suppose Ace would be 1 and 10,J,Q,K would be 10, so there would be 16 10's.

Get a random number between 0 and 51 to get the index of the array you want to use.  Once you use that index, set the value of that array = -1, and always check for -1 before using that index, and if it is -1, get another random value.

```
int [] deck = size 52 array with 4 of each card.
int random = get random number between 0 and 51.

while(deck[random] == -1){
   random = get random number between 0 and 51.
}
int card1 = deck[random]
deck[random] = -1;
```

something like that.. I just did that quickly, hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Actually, at a casino, blackjack games consist of 6 decks, thoroughly shuffled, in a shoe. There are actually 24 of each number across all 6 decks and 4 suits.

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight I prefer playing single deck blackjack in the casinos.  They still have it in all casinos.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the tips you requested:

- You need to introduce a variable to keep track of your sum. For example, you could initialize it with: `int sum = randomnum1 + randomnum2;` and keep adding the next card to it inside the loop: `sum += randomnum3;`
- You need to generate `randomnum3` inside the while loop. This way, you will get a different card every time. Basically, you have to call the random function every time you generate a card, not just once. Otherwise the value of `randomnum3` will be unchanged and you will get the same card over and over.
- To exit when you get to 21, you would have to use `if` and possibly `break` within the loop, once you have added the current card to the sum: `if(sum > 21) { break; }`
- Alternatively, you can set the value of `anotherCard` to `'n'` instead of using a `break`
- You should keep track of which cards the user has already gotten if you want to simulate an actual deck. This is not technically necessary for the program you appear to be writing though.

Comment: How do you generate a new card for randomnum3? I know how to add to running total (total += randomnum3;), but every time I want to get a new card, it gives me the same card number...

If you can help me there, I think I should be able to complete the program.

Comment: List item 2 addresses that issue. You need to put `int randomnum3 = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 10);` inside the while loop.

Comment: I edited the answer a little. Hopefully, it will be a bit more clear.

Comment: AHH, DUH! How come I missed that? THANK YOU!

Comment: No problem. We're all here to learn. Feel free to accept my answer if you like it :)

Comment: Definitely will! In regards to the total > 21: Would it be a Do-While Loop?

Comment: Yes. You want to do that check for every new card. Also, you have a regular while loop, not a do-while. Your logic would work just as well with a do-while, if you wanted to switch to it though.

Comment: OK, I'll work on this and let you know what I was able to get. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey Mad Physicist, can I contact you via email? I've tweaked my code a bit, but the issues I'm having:

1) When it asks me "Do I want to play again?" and I answer no, it still gives me 2 cards and total number.

2) ***Same question from above, but answer "yes"*** It starts with the question "Do you want another card?"

Comment: It would be easier if you asked another question with the updated code. You seem to be putting a lot of work into this, so I do not think that you will have any problems getting a good answer. It is always better to get more than one opinion, no matter how much you are willing to trust that opinion. I would have to see the way in which you decide whether or not to start a new game to find the problem (it seems that both issues are a manifestation of the same logic).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few simple improvements for you to look over.  I'll leave it like this as part of the joy of learning to program is in the discovery.  As a next step I'd suggest generating a dealers hand and then seeing if the player can beat it.  Good luck!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int card1 = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 10);
    int card2 = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 10);
    int total = card1 + card2;

    System.out.println(String.format("First cards: %d & %d.  Total %d", card1, card2, total));
    System.out.println();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Do you want another card? (y/n): ");
    char anotherCard = input.next().charAt(0);
    while (anotherCard != 'n' && total < 21) {
        int nextcard = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 10);
        total += nextcard;
        System.out.println(String.format("You drew a %d.  Your total is now %d", nextcard, total));

        if (total > 21) {
            System.out.println("You busted!");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Do you want another card? (y/n): ");
            anotherCard = input.next().charAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```