# Black Jack Game in Java

Tags: java, blackjack

### Problem statement

I have another thread on this, but I can't seem to locate it. Basically, I have a Black Jack game. The user is given two random cards (then those cards are added together, and display the total). Then it prompts user if they want another card (They pretty much will want to have a total lower than 21). If they choose "yes," they are given a random card number (they can keep getting a card, but should avoid going over 21), but if they choose "no," the game stops.

Here's the output I should get: [[blackjackoutput.jpg]](http://s14.postimg.org/hibuys45d/blackjackoutput.jpg)

And here's what I'm getting: [[output1.jpg]](http://s14.postimg.org/4d3c6d1c1/output1.jpg)

### Source code:

```
public class BlackJackGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int randomnum1 = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 10);
        int randomnum2 = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 10);
        int total;
        char anotherCard = 'y';
        char playAgain;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Prints cards player starts off with
        System.out.println("First cards: " + randomnum1 + ", " + randomnum2);

        // Sum of the 2 cards
        total = randomnum1 + randomnum2;

        // Prints Total
        System.out.println("Total: " + total);

        // Do While Loop that asks question to get lower than 21 or terminate.
        while (anotherCard != 'n') {
            if (total <= 21) {
                System.out.print("Do you want another card? (y/n): ");
                anotherCard = input.next().charAt(0);

                int randomnum3 = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 10);
                System.out.println("Card: " + randomnum3);

                total += randomnum3;
                System.out.println("Total: " + total);
            } else if (total > 21) {
                System.out.println("BUST.");

                System.out.print("Would you like to play again? (y/n): ");
                playAgain = input.next().charAt(0);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

### Issue

1. When I reach to 21, I choose "no," to stop the program. But, it continues to display the next card and the updated total.
2. When I "BUST." (Or go over 21). It'll ask me if I want to play. And on separate occasions, I choose "y" and it says "Bust." and asks me if I want to play again (it loops, says "BUST.", and asks me the same question, without being able to end the program). Same thing if I choose "no" it'll say "Bust." and ask me if I can want to play again.
3. How do you play the game again?

PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25554213/3802811) your other question? (This link will show you your activity on Stack Exchange: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3385997/)

Comment: It's an update from too many attempts. I want to know from anyone what I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: Sorry, I did not see that the formatter converted HTML entities...

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is a logic issue here:

```
 if (total <= 21) 
    {
      System.out.print("Do you want another card? (y/n): "); //<--------------
      anotherCard = input.next().charAt(0);

      int randomnum3 = (int) (1 + Math.random() * 10);

      System.out.println("Card: " + randomnum3);

      total += randomnum3;

      System.out.println("Total: " + total);
```

You need to check `if(anotherCard == 'n')` to break out of the loop

**Side Note**

This blackjack game should have a better distribution of random cards better modeled off  a 52 card deck